# Wrong Comparison of two list using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I had two `List`  of class `myListClass` Where

```
public class myListclass
{
    public Nullable<decimal> ClassId { get; set;}
    public Nullable<decimal> SectionId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> MediumId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> StreamId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ShiftId { get; set; }
}
```

where list1 is

```
List<myListclass> liAll = new List<myListclass>();
```

and items in `liAll` are

```
ClassId Section MediumId Stream  Shift
73     220       207    145       128
73     221       207    145       128
73     222       207    145       128
74     220       207    145       128
74     221       207    145       128
75     220       207    145       128
75     221       207    145       128
76     220       207    145       128
76     221       207    145       128
77     220       207    145       128
77     221       207    145       128
78     220       207    145       128
```

And list2 is

```
List<myListclass> liJoin = new List<myListclass>();
```

Where item in `liJoin` are

```
ClassId Section MediumId Stream  Shift
73     220       207    145       128
73     221       207    145       128
```

Now I want to select only those items into a list which are in `liAll` but not in `liJoin`

So wrote the following code:

```
List<myListclass> liFinal = new List<myListclass>(); 
liFinal = liAll.Where(w => !liJoin.Contains(w)).ToList();
```

but `liFinal` not giving me accurate  result it gives all items of `liAll`
So my questions are

1. what's wrong with above code ?
2. Better way to do this

   ### Updated code

   liFinal  =  liAll.Where(w => !liJoin.Select(s => s.ClassId ).Contains(w.ClassId) &&
               !liJoin.Select(s => s.MediumId ).Contains(w.MediumId) &&
               !liJoin.Select(s => s.SectionId ).Contains(w.SectionId) &&
               !liJoin.Select(s => s.ShiftId).Contains(w.ShiftId) &&
               !liJoin.Select(s => s.StreamId).Contains(w.StreamId)).ToList();

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it will compare that items by reference, you need to implement Equals

Comment: It will check if they are the same object, not all fields are equal

Comment: You need to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` and use the overloaded `Contains` method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ric how could i use IEquilityComparer

Comment: @Ric Equals should help I think, am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are right @wudzik but i compare each variable also wait i am updating my code

Comment: @wudzik absolutely, but if the OP wants to use `Contains` then the overload would be needed.

Comment: Using `decimal` for an Id is a very bad idea. Consider `int?`, `long?` or just `string`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i keep it mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you can use the LINQ `Except` method to get the missing elements:

```
List<myListclass> liFinal = liAll.Except(liJoin).ToList();
```

For this (and other equality-based operations) to work, you need to implement `IEquatable<T>` on your class:

```
public class myListclass : IEquatable<myListclass>
{
    public Nullable<decimal> ClassId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SectionId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> MediumId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> StreamId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ShiftId { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(myListclass other)
    {
        return
            other != null &&
            this.ClassId == other.ClassId &&
            this.SectionId == other.SectionId &&
            this.MediumId == other.MediumId &&
            this.StreamId == other.StreamId &&
            this.ShiftId == other.ShiftId;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as myListclass);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/1149773
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + ClassId.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + SectionId.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + MediumId.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + StreamId.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + ShiftId.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation for the `GetHashCode()` method is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/1149773) by Jon Skeet.

Comment: Except returning Null

Comment: I suppose this one is easier then `operator overloading`, by the way; thanks for sharing that useful link, i wasn't aware of that post

Comment: @Zefnus: I agree with your addition of a proper hyperlink to the `GetHashCode` answer, but I've reverted your removal of the URL from the code. If someone chooses to copy-and-paste the code, I'd rather they copied the URL too.

Comment: @Douglas You'r right, i didn't think that way. And now with the last edit it's perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to override Equals method for your class MyListClass.

Follow this link. This will tell you how to implement this for your class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183755.aspx

Here is the snipped which I use for overriding equal methods.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return Equals(obj as $className$);
}
internal bool Equals($className$ other)
{
    // If parameter is null, return false. 
    if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        return false;

    // Optimization for a common success case. 
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        return true;

    return // TODO: compare this.Memeber1 == other.Member2,
    // if equal return true,
}
```

Comment: always override GetHashCode!

Comment: @wudzik We can, but I have heard bad things about overriding GetHashCode method, so I don't use that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Enumerable.Except();`

```
liFinal = liAll.Except(liJoin);
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more

Comment: @wudzik have you seen the link? it contains implementations for both overloads of the Enumerable.Except.. including IEqualityComparer

Comment: It is not an answer because error was not using Contains instead of Except, but not implementing `Equals`

Comment: @wudzik i know. thats why i pointed him to msdn article on what to do and didnt provide a specific code example. Zefnus did that, not me. I wanted him to figure it out using the docs

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var list = liAll.Except(liJoin);
```

Comment: Except returning Null